# Change element style without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet, element

Is there a way to change CSS style for specified element **without using JavaScript**?

I don't want to use JS because of some browsers which do not support, or have disabled it...

**Concrete example:**
I have 2 DIVs (`#menu` and `#content`) and I want to set `min-height` CSS property of `#content` to actual `height` property of `#menu` (so if the `#menu` would be longer than `#content`, `#content`'s and `#menu`'s heights would be equal).

Comment: no. it's not possible. well - there are css expressions. their support is way worse than that of js(only ie <8 hehe). You need scripting and no scripting language on the web is more widely supported than JavaScript.

Comment: Sounds like you want to [clear floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) based on your example.

Comment: I dnt understand you say no javascript and you have conveniently tagges your question with javascript.

Comment: if you're just trying to make equal columns - use either clear floats or set holder container to overflow:auto

Comment: Javascript has very good support in most modern browsers. For simple task such yours be free to use Javascript.

Comment: I say - screw people who turn JS off intentionally. They really should expect 80% of websites not to work.

Comment: Clearing floats is exactly what I need! Thanks.

Comment: @Marcel - please add what you said as Answer as well so the OP can accept it and mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem can be solved with simple plain CSS. For the purpose of demonstration I am going to assume that you have a menu on the left side of your web page and with the rest of the page to follow its height. That behavior is easily achieved by combining floats and overflows.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    width: 98%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu {
    float: left;
    width:30%;
}
```

The trick is in using `overflow:hidden` on the outside wrapper which will make the content height always adjust to the height of the menu.